# How to hide mw:editsection blocks on parsed Mediawiki page?

Tags: php, mediawiki

When I try to get parsed needle page using:

```
$parser = new Parser();
$parserOptions = new ParserOptions();
$parserOptions->setEditSection(false);
$title = Title::newFromText('Title');
$article = WikiPage::factory($title);
$bodyText = $parser->parse($article->getText(), $title, $parserOptions)->mText;
```

I receive parsed article with `mw:editsection` blocks. How to hide it?

Comment: apart from your question, I think your approach isn't very good at all. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve html formatted text without `mw:editsection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getText()` instead `mText` return text in html format without `mw:editsection`. 
For example: `$bodyText = $parser->parse($article->getText(), $title, $parserOptions)->getText();`